# What does "Your branch is up-to-date with origin/master" error mean?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I try to commit my changes in IntelliJ IDEA, it brings up an error dialog box saying the commit ended in error and that the files were not committed and then it says:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

The event log shows:

```
12:02:21 0 files committed, 5 files failed to commit: this is a commit message
```

What does this mean?

Comment: That's not an error, that's just a information. The "error" is explained below "*nothing to commit, working directory clean*". You have no changes which could be commited.

Comment: Normally,  when I have no changes, it just says "Nothing to commit" in a green bubble. This time, it shows a list of files that have changed and are to be commited. It even specifically says that it "failed to commit 5 files"

Comment: Why don't you include that error message then?